# How to get localized *.resx Files (embedded Resource)

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, localization

I have my loacalized *.resx files in another project to which I set a reference (it's a solution with mulltiple projects, so we have a *.Common project where we have styles, localization...). by now I have two *resx:

- TextObjects.resx ------> english/invariant
- TextObjects.de.resx --> german

How can i get these Files (the cultures of it)? Because I use [WPFLocalizeExtension](https://github.com/SeriousM/WPFLocalizationExtension) the *.resx-files need to be embedded resources.
I found only a way to watch inside the Resourcefile and get it's Keys, but not how many and which files i have.

Also I face two other problems:

1. The default invariant Language ist shown as this. Is there a way, without an Converter, to show it as english?
2. I like do set the systems CurrentCulture as first culture. If there is no localization for that the Extension correctly uses the Invariant Localization. **BUT** if the language doesn't exist it still get added to the `MergedAvailableCultures` and is as a result also shown in the `ComboBox` to which i bound this list. How can I avoid this?